# How to update base price of product by store id using magento 2 rest api?

Tags: php, magento, postman, magento2

I am trying to update base price of product by store id and product SKU using POSTMAN. But, getting error `Invalid Attribute`. Sometimes it works fine. I tried to change product attributes to if it cause to this issue but it didn't resolved the issue.

Request URL -

```
{{url}}/V1/products/base-prices
```

Request Body -

```
{
    "prices": [
        {
            "price": 38,
            "store_id": 4,
            "sku": "WEBPRICETEST"
        }
    ]
}
```

Response -

```
[
    {
        "message": "Invalid attribute %fieldName = %fieldValue.",
        "parameters": [
            "SKU",
            "WEBPRICETEST"
        ]
    }
]
```

There is no any traces in error log.

Comment: Please share both success and error request/response , so we can trace the difference

Comment: For success, I am getting empty array.

Comment: can you please share both success and error request payload?

Comment: Payloads are same as well. But, I have noticed this error occurs for few SKU's.

Answer (score 1):

This error could appear if you try to use the wrong type of a request.

Try this

POST(not PUT or any other): <domain>/rest/V1/products/base-prices

OR (for async request): POST  <domain>/rest/async/V1/products/base-prices

Body

```
{
  "prices": [
  {
    "price": 222,
    "store_id": 2,
    "sku": "SKU-1"
  },
  {
    "price": 333,
    "store_id": 2,
    "sku": "SKU-2"
  }
  ]
}
```

Don't forget to set headers:

Content-Type :  application/json

Authorization: Bearer <Your Access Token>

Answer (score 0):

So basically if both success and error request payload are some and it gives error with few of SKUs then it may be the type of product which is causing error. The endpoint you are using will only update below types of product base price.

Simple,
Virtual,
Downloadable,
Bundle (fixed price type only).

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/rest/modules/catalog-pricing.html#set-base-prices

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But both are simple products.

Answer (score 0):

Magento already supports getting prices by store. You just need to add store_code and URL: {{url}}/{store code}/V1/products/base-prices

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But getting error - `"message": "Specified request cannot be processed."`

Comment: The syntax of Magento 2 Api is
http://<:host:>/rest/<:store_code:>/<:api_path>
Please make sure you are entering the correct store code. Here store_code can be any one of the "store view" of your Magento2 instance. You can get the store code in admin panel